# Помощь с запросом MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня База данных в которой миллион строк (в каждой по одному слову), есть список (вне базы данных) который состоит из тысячи строк (в каждой по одному слову).
Возможно ли составить ОДИН запрос, который будет проверять сразу все слова из списка на наличие в базе данных, а остальные допустим убирать?

Например в БД у меня строки:

```
"one"
"two"
"three"
"four"
"five"
"six"
```

В списке:

```
"one"
"five"
"seven"
"eight"
```

Нужно что бы после запроса у меня остались только "seven","eight".

Comment: Да, можно. `DELETE .. WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Для коротких списков подойдёт что-то вроде 
`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country NOT IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');`

Если список слов длинный, загрузите его в отдельную таблицу, а дальше
`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country NOT IN (SELECT Country FROM Suppliers);`

Это для выбора.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Примите ответ.